# Debugging a Travis CI process?

Tags: gdb, remote-debugging, travis-ci

I am trying to figure out why my Travis CI tests fail [here](https://travis-ci.org/d33tah/nmap/jobs/88006938). It looks like an infinite loop in one of the programs and I'm eager to run gdb there and take a look inside. I assume that the Travis instance is behind NAT, so just connecting to a GDB server would be complicated. Is there a way to make the gdb server connect to me? Do I have any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found:

https://github.com/fniephaus/travis-remote-shell

This is a project that uses Ngrok to open a TCP port and then creates a reverse shell there. I hadn't tried it though.

Comment: Have you found any good tools that help debug build errors from Travis ? I'm stuck now and don't know what to do with it. Everything works fine on the development server and on AWS but Travis is giving me build error.